# SLES 12 Service start and stop order doesnt work

Tags: shutdown, services, systemd, suse, systemctl

my system runs on suse enterprise 12 sp2.

I have two services sapinit and sapcontrol. At startup the service sapinit has to be started before the sapcontrol service can start and at shutdown or stop the sapcontrol service has to be stopped so that the sapinit can stop.

I created both scripts as following and added them via insserv.

Header of /etc/init.d/sapinit

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sapinit
# Required-Start: $network $syslog $remote_fs $time
# X-UnitedLinux-Should-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# X-Stop-After: $sapcontrol
# Default-Start: 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Start the sapstartsrv
# Description: Start the startsapsrv 
### END INIT INFO
```

Header of /etc/init.d/sapcontrol

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sapcontrol
# Required-Start: $sapinit
# Required-Stop: $network $syslog $remote_fs $time $sapinit
# Default-Start: 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Description: Start and Stop SAP System as system changed
# Short-Description: start and stop SAP
### END INIT INFO
```

For this LSB service i defined Required-Stop and Required-Start for correct order, but the system doesnt care.

On Startup the service sapcontrol is started first and needs about 25sec so after 20 sec the sapinit service is started and finished after 2 sec. So the sapinit is finished first, but this is not the purpose i need to start the sapcontrol after the sapinit is completley finished.

[Screenshot: systemctl status sapinit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4r2e.png)

[Screenshot: systemctl status sapcontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5uwU.png)

Same for the stop order, when i reboot or shutdown the system the sapinit is stopped nearly first and the sapcontrol is stopped anywhere, but i need to stop the sapcontrol bevore the sapinit.

```
sapinit stopped:  + Wed Aug 1 06:56:08 UTC 2018
sapcontrol stopped:  + Wed Aug 1 06:56:28 UTC 2018
```

[Screenshot: shuting down the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOL0l.png)

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: From user [novice](https://superuser.com/users/856528/novice): Have you tried changing `$sapinit` to `sapinit` in the /etc/init.d/sapcontrol?  According to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/) page, `$` in the headers indicates a virtual facility name.

Comment: The poster seems not to want to tell the community. I guess that was the problem.

Comment: I tried changine `$sapinit` to `sapinit`, but still didnt work.
I was kinda bussy. @U.Windl

Comment: As SLES12 uses systemd, LSB scripts are actually wrapped in systemd units. You could try to override an "After=" condition (using `systemctl edit ...`).